# ¿Como puedo obtener un Json de ciudades de un pais en concreto?

Tags: java, json, array, eclipse

Codigo java que lee todo el json obtenido desde la consulta a base de datos

```java
private static void construirMap(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        ciudades = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject ciudad = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ciudades.put(ciudad.optString("cdIso") + "_" + ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("cdIso").equals("CO"), ciudad);
        System.out.println(ciudad);
           }
        }
```

El Json se arma desde  una consulta desde base datos, 
el Json armado trae mucha informacion de varios paises 
solo necesito la informacion de uno pero noce como separarlo

```
{
    "dsNombre": "Abejorral",
    "cdDane": "002",
    "nmId": 1,
    "departamento": {
        "dsNombre": "Antioquia",
        "cdDane": "05",
        "cdIso": "CO-ANT",
        "pais": {
            "dsNombre": "Colombia",
            "cdIso": "CO"
        }
    }
},
{
    "dsNombre": "Abriaqui",
    "cdDane": "004",
    "nmId": 3,
    "departamento": {
        "dsNombre": "Antioquia",
        "cdDane": "05",
        "cdIso": "CO-ANT",
        "pais": {
            "dsNombre": "Colombia",
            "cdIso": "CO"
        }
    }
}, {
 "nmId": 4928,
  "dsNombre": "Ig",
  "departamento": {
   "cdIso": "SI-037",
     "dsNombre": "Ig",
     "pais": {
      "cdIso": "SI",
     "dsNombre": "Eslovenia"
            },
            "cdDane": "SI-037"
        },
        "cdDane": "001"
    }
```

pd: no puedo limitar la consulta por que utilizo los otros paises en otro metodo solo necesito separar la información de la ciudades y departametos de un pais en concreto

Este Json es una version miniatura del Json real que almacena todo la informacion de los paises

Comment: haz intentado usar un if para filtrar los datos que guardas en tu hashmap?

Comment: ya intente pero no me funciono depronto hice algo mal ¿me podrias dar un ejemplo como lo harias? para tener mas claridad

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar con un if antes de guardar en tu hashmap, te quedaría algo como esto:

```
private static void construirMap(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        ciudades = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject ciudad = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           if (ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("cdIso").toString().equals("CO")){ //puedes reempalzar "CO" por el país a buscar
                 ciudades.put(ciudad.optString("cdIso") + "_" + 
                 ciudad.getJSONObject("departamento").optString("cdIso"), ciudad);
                 System.out.println(ciudad);
           }   
        }
}
```

El if que agregué antes de tu método, comprobará que el país que está recibiendo por ese JSON sea el designado (en el ejemplo "CO") y lo mostrará y guaradará en el hashmap sólo si cumple la condición. El `equals` que tenías en la sección al momento de guardar, no parece tener sentido ahí.

Comment: Gracias Amigo  mi condicional estaba malo  , pero esto me ayudo  y me sirvio